# How can I managed to get a reverse DNS assigned to an elastic IP if I use elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have multiple environments on Elastic Beanstalk. Each environment is assigned a number of ec2 depending on traffic.

I recently started looking at amazon's simple email service. Seeing that it seems excellent, I have requested a limit increase and also a removal of the throttle on port 25.

upon accepting my request, AWS told me that DNS record entries are commonly considered in anti-SPAM filters and that they recommend assigning a reverse DNS record to the Elastic IP address I use to send emails

If I was using only EC2 instances, it will be easy for me to create an elastic IP and submit it to them so that I could get the reverse DNS. However, I am using Elastic Beanstalk, which has multiple Ec2s with different addresses.

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible somehow to get an elastic IP if I use elastic Beanstalk?
2. Is it essential to have a reverse DNS?
3. If I don't have it, will the emails that I send with SES (SMTP) go directly to spams?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: who told you so, https://aws.amazon.com/ses/faqs/ this says we dont need to setup reverse dns

Comment: @ArunK on their website : https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/contacts?#/rdns-limits if you click on "info" to the right of the title "Elastic IPs information". Furthermore, I was comunicating with AWS, this is what they told me : " .. Because reverse DNS record entries are commonly considered in anti-SPAM filters, we recommend assigning a reverse DNS record to the Elastic IP address you use to send email to third parties. Please use the form located at this link to request a reverse DNS entry:https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request"

Comment: Did you check the link I gave you. It says the opposite